# how to remove Date Column gives Error in Rdlc report? and want to display mysql date in Report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I am using asp.net and mysql. In Rdlc report i can't able to display the Date.

First of all it gives an error Like Can't able to convert mysql date to system.date. so i add Allow Zero Datetime=true; in connection string. now the report shows...

But its display #Error in the Report column.

DataSet Name is - mcubicDataSet.xsd 
DataDable Name is - fo_reserv

Preview Data in VS2010 : -

[image]

Rdlc report :-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two instances when this happened to me, and 3 solutions

1. The rdlc report is bound to a dataset that is generated by Visual Studio through your MySql connector. Sometimes the dataset that is created has date columns with the **MySqlDateTime** instead of the default **System.DateTime**. 
   To see this Open Your Report.rdlc, then view report data *(Ctrl+Alt+D)* to see the dataSet, right click for properties then check the datatypes in the columns.[image]
   Go to the file that represents the data source where the dataset comes from and open the designer file in the coding window. In my case mine is called pos_dbDataSet.xsd, with a designer file called pos_dbDataSet.Designer.cs Once you open it you can do a string replacement *(Ctrl + H)* on the date dataTypes find: **MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime** relpace with: **System.DateTime** . 
   Be careful to Replace all in the Current Document ONLY. Though this change may not refrect on your report dataset, the report should run.

[image]
2. Use the DataSource Configuration Wizard to rebuild the DataSource/Datasets.

3. (Less likely) The rdlc report uses the date formats of your operating system, hence there might be a conflict between the MySql format and the OS format. What resolved the issue for me was changing my datetime formats on the Calender or Region settings of my computer to better match the database formats. I was using UK formats and changed to US formats.

[Calender/Format Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8KGb.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Change the fieldtype in database from datetime to text . this error occours because of fieldtype mismatch .